# Extrair a lista de <li>'s com xpath

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Olá,

Estou a desenvolver um aplicativo com java + selenium
Tenho o segundo elemento web:

```
WebElement results = ( new WebDriverWait( driver, timeout  ) ).until( ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated( By.id( "local" ) ) );
```

Onde o id=local é uma div que contém dentro uma lista html, do tipo:

```
<div id="local">
<ul>
<li>
   <span>texto</span>
</li>
<li>
   <span>texto</span>
</li>
<li>
   <span>texto</span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Queria extrair o texto de todos os . Não sei como obter a lista de li's com xpath a partir da div no WebElement. Depois queria obter uma lista em java com todos os li, para iterar e assim obter cada span.

Alguma ideia de como fazer ? Não sei como ir buscar com xpath os nomes que pretendo.

É possível extrair de uma só vez todos os span com xpath?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via xpath você vai conseguir acessar todos os spans pela expressão:

```
//div[@id = 'local']/ul/li/span
```

Esta expressão diz que ele irá entrar na div com o id `local` percorrer cada `ul`, para cada ul ele irá percorrer cada `li` e para cada li ele irá devolver cada `span`.

Dito isto, você pode fazer a busca no `selenium` utilizando o `findElements` e passando o `By.xpath`, ou da forma que você está utilizando você pode utilizar o `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy`

Segue abaixo o código:

```
String xPath = "//div[@id = 'local']/ul/li/span";
List<WebElement> results = (new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout))
        .until(ExpectedConditions
                .visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
                        By.xpath(xPath)
                )
);
```

Agora em `results` você terá a lista de todos os `span's` agora se você quiser a lista de todas as `li's` basta alterar o xpath apagando o `/span`
Para fazer o teste do `xpath` gosto de utilizar o [freeformatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado pela resposta e pela explicação :)